# Guardar información en Arrays en Bash

Tags: bash

Estoy haciendo un escáner de puertos como ejercicio para aprender bash, quiero que cada puerto, dependiendo de si está abierto o cerrado se guarde en un array, pero no consigo el resultado que espero. Esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora:

```
declare -A puertos

puertos=(
        [abierto]=""
        [cerrado]=""
        )
read -p 'Introduce un dominio: ' domain

for port in {22..80}; do
  if echo >/dev/tcp/$domain/$port; then
    ${puertos[abierto]}=$port
    echo ${puertos[abierto]}
  else
    ${puertos[cerrado]}=$port
    echo ${puertos[cerrado]}
  fi
done 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Eliminar `${...}` de los comandos `${puertos[abierto]}=$port` y `${puertos[cerrado]}=$port` para obtener `puertos[abierto]=$port` y `puertos[cerrado]=$port`. No use `${...}` para realizar la asignación de valores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que quieres hacer esto (después de un mensaje anterior tuyo y eliminado) :

```bash
#! /bin/bash

declare -A puertos

puertos=(
        [abierto]=""
        [cerrado]=""
        )
read -r -p 'Introduce un dominio: ' domain

for port in {22..80}; do
  if echo >/dev/tcp/$domain/$port; then
    puertos[abierto]+="$port "
  else
    puertos[cerrado]+="$port "
  fi
done 2>/dev/null

echo abierto=${puertos[abierto]}
echo cerrado=${puertos[cerrado]}
```

Comment: Perfecto, así es, esto resuelve mi problema, muchisimas gracias por el aporte!!